# How to start immediately an Angular 2 Observable when using interval

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following **Angular 2** service that is fetching data every 5 seconds:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class DataService{
  getData():{
    return Observable
        .interval(5000)
        .flatMap(() => this.http.get('http://some_url'))
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }
```

Is there a way to have this service executing the request at the start? Otherwise it will wait for 5 seconds before the first execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `interval` with [`timer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer), as it allows you to specify an initial delay:

```
getData():{
  return Observable
    .timer(0, 5000)
    .flatMap(() => this.http.get('http://some_url'))
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
}
```