# Observable.interval AJAX Call - How to Make Call Before Interval

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a polling set up to make AJAX calls on an interval using an Observable. Here's my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class HttpAPIService {
  metrics: Object;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    // https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-2-http
    this.getMetrics('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments').subscribe(data => this.metrics = data);
  }

  getMetrics(url: string) {
    return Observable.interval(5000)
      .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url))
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

}
```

The code waits 5 seconds before doing the first AJAX call. How can I change it so that the first AJAX call happens immediately? Also, if I use the following command in another module, will the subscription make my variable data-binded to the API call that is being called every 5 seconds?

```
this.variableIWantToBind = this.httpAPIService.getMetrics('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments').subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612945/how-to-get-an-observable-to-return-data-immediately-and-every-5-seconds-thereaft

Comment: I think `.startWith(0)` is still supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start immediately an Angular 2 Observable when using interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451673/how-to-start-immediately-an-angular-2-observable-when-using-interval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .startWith(0) as @Zircon pointed out